# Content overflows outside the <div>

Tags: css, html, overflow

The content of a `<div>` element, if it has no spaces, overflows outside the container.

Is there a trick to fix this with a new line, on all browsers?

For example:

```
<div style="width: 500px;">

    <div style="border: 1px solid #000;">
        <p>http://www.trendn.com/timthumb.php?src=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.blogcdn.com%2Fwww.engadget.com%2Fmedia%2F2011%2F04%2F11x0419n873422_thumbnail.jpg</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: If you could add some context (markup/css) that demonstrates your issue, that would be helpful.

Comment: Question updated with an example. There's a border to see the overflow.

Comment: Yeesh. If you want all the content to display just on different lines, use thirtydot's css.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly: (not sure that I do, as I'm posting a different answer to those already here)

Use the [`white-space` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/white-space) (or an equivalent property for IE).

```
#divElement {
    word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE 5.5-7 */
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox 1.0-2.0 */
    white-space: pre-wrap;      /* current browsers */
}
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/RE5uG/

Comment: Using thirydot's jsfiddle applied to Marco's supplied markup/style: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/RE5uG/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `overflow` css declaration.

See: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/overflow.html

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/pr2k7/

Answer (score 0):

use [CSS overlflow](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_overflow.asp) with `hidden`